# How to remove ssl configuration file from apache on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ssl, apache2

I moved a website / domain to another server. On the original server there are still configuration file for both http and https. With a2dissite i removed the file for the http but is there a similar command for the https?

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody else has chimed in, I'll give it a stab.  The 'a2dissite' implies Apache2, so we're looking for a configuration (conf) file.  On Ubuntu or Debian, that would be in /etc/apache2/conf-available.  Find the one that begins with ' and use the 'a2disconf' command to remove it from /etc/apache2/conf-enabled, and then use 'systemctl reload apache2' to unload it from the Apache server.  You can then remove the disabled conf file if you so desire. Hope this helps!